# Nested types in Scala

Tags: scala, generics, types

I have two questions about nested types in Scala.

Imagine I have this kinda trait;

```
trait ScanList[E] {
  sealed trait Command
  case object Recover extends Command
  case class Remove(item: E) extends Command

  sealed trait Event
  case class Removed(item: E) extends Event
}
```

And now I want to write a generic trait over this like this (the problems are encoded in the pattern matches as comment):

```
trait ScanListProcessor[E] {
    type SL = ScanList[E]

    def process(msg: SL#Command) = {
        msg match {
            case u:SL#Remove => // how can instantiate SL#Removed here?
            case SL#Recover => //cannot match on nested objects?
        }
    }
}
```

The reason for using a trait is that I can derive new implementations of ScanList. In this trait I also have operations like `def shouldProcess(item: E): Boolean`. For each implementation of `ScanList[E]` I would like to write generic behaviour like depicted above.

1. How can pattern match on nested object in a generic type?
2. Is it possible to instantiate from a type constructor? For example: `SL#Removed`? I guess it's the same having a generic parameter and trying to construct a value from that, type classes would solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nested traits, class, and objects in Scala act like inner classes in Java. Any instance of them that you create is associated with an instance of the parent class/trait that they are created from. So continuing from your example:

```
val sl1 = new ScanList[Int] {}
val sl2 = new ScanList[Int] {}
val r1 = sl1.Removed(1) // has type sl1.Removed
val r2 = sl2.Removed(2) // has type sl2.Removed
val rs = List(r1, r2) // has type List[ScanList[Int]#Removed]
```

You can pattern match on them like:

```
rs match {
  case List(sl1.Removed(x), sl2.Removed(y)) => (x, y)
}
```

Pattern matching requires that you explicitly references the parent instance that the nested instance belongs to. Here, we separately match on `sl1.Removed` and `sl2.Removed`.

As for you second question, you cannot create a `SL#Removed` without having a parent instance available. With one, it is as simple as `sl1.Removed(1)`.

Your `ScanListProcessor` could be rewritten to take the `ScanList` it operates on as a value:

```
class ScanListProcessor[E](val sl: ScanList[E]) {
    def process(msg: sl.Command) = {
        msg match {
            case sl.Remove(x) => sl.Removed(x)
            case sl.Recover => ???
        }
    }
}
```

But this is awkward, and nested types probably aren't needed here. If all you want to do is group some traits, classes etc. together in a namespace, then put them in a `package` or `object` instead of a `trait` or `class`. In this case you would need to move the type parameter `E` down onto `Remove` and `Removed` themselves:

```
object ScanList {
  sealed trait Command
  case object Recover extends Command
  case class Remove[E](item: E) extends Command

  sealed trait Event
  case class Removed[E](item: E) extends Event
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know you can put these case classes/object inside a object/package. Thing is I'm deriving new implementations from it (deriving to a object).

Comment: I think passing the value inside another processor and delegating it's concern is a quite nice idea :) Thanks